# Python: `enum.auto()` Generating Warning That Parameter is Unfilled

Tags: python, enums, pycharm, warnings

I have the below code that defines an enum and uses `enum.auto()` to give entries generated values starting from 1:

```
from enum import Enum, auto


class Colors(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
    YELLOW = auto()


def main():
    print(Colors.RED.value)
    print(Colors.BLUE.value)
    print(Colors.YELLOW.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

The code works fine and used to not have any warnings, but after updating PyCharm today, I am now getting the following warning for `auto()`:

```
Parameter(s) unfilled 
Possible callees: 
EnumMeta.__call__(cls: Type[_T], value, names: None = ...) 
EnumMeta.__call__(cls: EnumMeta, value: str, names: Union[str, Iterable[str], Iterable[Iterable[str]], Mapping[str, Any]], *, module: Optional[str] = ..., qualname: Optional[str] = ..., type: Optional[type] = ..., start: int = ..., boundary: Optional[FlagBoundary] = ...) 
EnumMeta.__call__(cls: Type[_T], value, names: None = ...) 
EnumMeta.__call__(cls: EnumMeta, value: str, names: Union[str, Iterable[str], Iterable[Iterable[str]], Mapping[str, Any]], *, module: Optional[str] = ..., qualname: Optional[str] = ..., type: Optional[type] = ..., start: int = ...)
```

I checked the ***[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/enum.html#enum.auto)*** but couldn't find anything relevant, as all the examples still use `auto()` without any parameters.

I assume the new warning is because PyCharm is using updated Python linting rules.

How do I resolve this warning?

***UPDATE 1:***

It seems that PyCharm is detecting `enum.auto()` as `enum.auto(IntFlag)`, thus the warning that the parameter is unfilled:

[image]

I will also report this issue to the PyCharm devs. Perhaps it's a bug.

***UPDATE 2:***

Nevermind, everyone. I just found out this was a bug and was reported a month ago ***[here.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53388/PyCharm-thinks-enum.auto()-needs-an-argument)***

***UPDATE 3:***

The bug has finally been fixed!

Comment: Not sure, but you can check if the python version of your configuration (up right) "edit configuration" is the same as the one in the interpreter (down right) python interperter.

Comment: Which pycharm and python interpreter version are you using? looking at pycharm's latest update changelog they haven't changed anything related to python linting or enums

Comment: I'm using Python `3.9.6`, and my PyCharm is `Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64`, the latest at the moment.

Comment: Using PyCharm 2021.2.2 with Python 3.9.0 there are no errors nor warnings for the example code.

Comment: @bad_coder Yeah, older versions of PyCharm don't produce warnings for the example code. But PyCharm Community `2022.1` does for Python `3.9.6`.

Comment: Nevermind, everyone. I just found that it's a bug. It was reported a month ago here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53388/PyCharm-thinks-enum.auto()-needs-an-argument.

Comment: I didn't have time to further check on this when I commented, but I can tell you from experience whenever a `MetaEnum (...) Type[_T]` linter warning appears it's a PyCharm bug. I've seen that general warning come and go over the years. Good detective work finding it on JetBrains bugtracker!

Comment: @bad_coder Haha, I only found out about it while I was logging the issue myself. It popped up in the possible duplicate issues section.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Nevermind, everyone. I just found out this was a bug and was reported a month ago ***[here.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53388/PyCharm-thinks-enum.auto()-needs-an-argument)***

***UPDATE:***

The bug has finally been fixed!

Answer (score 6):

This is an IDE bug (as already mentioned by OP) and you should suppress the warning as such:

```
# noinspection PyArgumentList
class Colors(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
    YELLOW = auto()
```

Comment: This is a good workaround for the time being (and the bug has been around for months now), but those who do this should also add a `TODO` so they don't forget to remove the warning suppressions once the bug gets fixed.